# Logging all threads that acquired lock on my object

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to trace all threads that acquired lock on one of my objects.

**Is it possible to hook into implicit synchronization mechanism in java and log thread id (or some other information) whenever any thread acquires the lock?**

As far as I know, there is no method I could *just override*. I did not find anything useful in the reflection api either. I did not find any external tool that would be able to trace locks (VisualVM traces only cpu and memory usage, FindBugs uses static analysis, javapathfinder seems to be able to test only small non-awt applications).

Edit:
There seems to be a very similar question [In Java, how to log a message every time a given object's monitor is entered or exited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601351/in-java-how-to-log-a-message-every-time-a-given-objects-monitor-is-entered-or)

Comment: I like jstack. It shows all threads and their waiting status.

Comment: Unfortunately jstack wont help me. It provides only a snapshot while I need to trace all changes.

Comment: correct, but in case of locking problems you'll have a positive probability of catching some WAIT situations. Repeatedly executing jstack will give you an indication of hot spots and the stack traces of the threads, which gives you an idea where to look in your source. The threads holding the locks tend to be more interesting than the ones waiting, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seams that it can only be achieved with bytecode manipulation. Fortunately, bytecode manipulation is not so difficult (thanks to the [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)).

I created a java agent with custom `java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer` to modify classes at load time. The class loader intercepts all synchronized blocks (they start with `MONITORENTER` instruction) and synchronized methods (they do **not** start with `MONITORENTER` instruction) and inserts a call to a tracing function at these locations.

Because the tracing function is called whenever **any** thread enters **any** synchronized section it takes the lock object as an argument so I can decide whether I am interested in that object or not.

```
public static void trace(Object lock) {
    if (lock instanceof TraceMe) {
        // Do whatever you want here.
    }
}
```

Code of the agent can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/prvak/9413697). Compile it into a jar file and add following MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.example.LockTracerAgent
```

Run it with:

```
    java -Xbootclasspath/p:asm-4.2.jar:myapp.jar -javaagent:myagent.jar -jar myapp.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem your most likely solution that would work correctly in all cases (short of requiring every usage to call a custom lock function) is to do bytecode instrumentation. You would find all cases of the monitorenter and monitorexit and add your own special instructions in those cases. Two resources that can help are: http://www.correlsense.com/blog/java-bytecode-instrumentation-an-introduction/ (which is a blog post that has some info) and http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/manual.html (which is a library that could help you).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer pushed me in the right direction. I would like to upvote it but I do not have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way. You can poll `ThreadMXBean` to find out which thread is holding which lock, but this won't help you because you can't log **whenever** a thread acquires a particular lock.

You could however put log statements in the synchronized block if the usage is such that your IDE can tell you all the places it's been used.

Failing that you might have to replace the monitor object with something else and have your tracing code there.

Answer (score 0):

If instrumentation of the code is acceptable you could add a "log" statement to the synchronized block that would use Thread.currentThread() to get the current thread and an IdentityHashMap to associate the synchronized object with a collection of thread names.  Of course, threads can have the same name and you might have to filter the execution of the log invocation so you're not overwhelmed with object->thread associations.